# How can I increase the font size in PlotLabel?

Tags: plotting

Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[r*(y/x), {x, 20, 42}, {y, 20, 42}, 
  ContourStyle -> 
   Directive[RGBColor[1., 0.77, 0.], Opacity[1.], 
    AbsoluteThickness[1.999], Dashed], ContourLabels -> False, 
  Contours -> {27, 28, 28.5, 29.5, 47, 49, 50, 52, 94, 96, 97, 99}, 
  ContourShading -> {Red, Orange, Red, Orange, LightGray, Orange, Red,
     Orange, LightGray, Orange, Red, Orange, Red},

PlotLabel -> 
   Row[{"Was I Speedy? if your speedometer reads ", 
     NumberForm[r, {4, 0}], " mph, you're actually traveling to: ", 
     NumberForm[r*y/x, {4, 0}], mph}],

Axes -> True, Ticks -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 674, AxesOrigin -> {20, 20}, AspectRatio -> 0.65, 
  Epilog -> {{Dashed, Line[{{x, 42}, {x, y}}], 
     Line[{{20, y}, {x, y}}]}, {AbsolutePointSize[32], 
     Inset[car, {x, y}]}}], {{x, 30, "old tire diameter inches"}, 20, 
  42, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{y, 30, 
   "new tire diameter inches"}, 20, 42, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{r, 45, "Speedometer reading in mph"}, 
  30, 80, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

[image: Speedometer]

I think the title of my project is displaying very small and I would like be with a larger font. I have tried different strategies but with no success.
If someone can help me I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: `PlotLabel->Style["your text", 30]`

Comment: Or add `,FontSize->40` to all your StyleBox-es

Comment: sorry, I still not able to change the font size, I have been trying the whole day but I just can do it. Anyways, thank you for taking your time and answer my question. If you have other strategy, please let me know.

Comment: See answer below. PS can you improve the layout of your question? Instructions are in the top right corner of the edit box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really is not different from what I suggested in comments. I now `Map`(`/@`) `Style` to every part of the title, but you could have done it manually in each string:

```
PlotLabel -> 
 Row[Style[#, 16] & /@ {"Was I Speedy? if your speedometer reads ", 
    NumberForm[r, {4, 0}], " mph, you're actually traveling to: ", 
    NumberForm[r*y/x, {4, 0}], "mph"}]
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to fix it with your help.